# Convergence of linear map on a subset implies convergence on the span?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space, and that I have a sequence of linear maps $(T_{n})_{n\geq1}$ such that $T_{n}(x) \to T(x)$ for all $x\in K$ where, $K \subset X$.

Since $T$ is linear does it follow that $T_{n}(x) \to T(x)$ for all $x\in \rm span(K)$? In finite dimensions this is clear, but I am not sure if anything changes in infinite dimensions since I am unclear on the definition of $\rm span(K)$ in this case (my only knowledge of $\rm span$ comes from linear algebra, so I am not sure if an alternate and more general definition is required).

Comment: Hint: by definition, the span of a set of vectors $K$ is the set of all *finite* linear combinations of vectors belonging to $K$. So in infinite dimensions, even if $K$ is infinite dimensional, its span is defined as all finite combinations of its elements.

Comment: @AlexR. Okay great, thanks! from this definition the answer is easy

Answer (score 0):

If the definition is unchanged in the infinite case as suggested by Alex R., then the answer is trivial since if $w \in \rm span(K)$ then $w$ can be written as $w= \sum_{j=1}^{J(w)} \lambda_{j}w_{j}$ where $w_{j} \in K$ for all $j$, and $J(w)<\infty$ is a finite number which depends on $w$. Thus: $$T_{n}(w) = \sum_{j=1}^{J} \lambda_{j}T_{n}(w_{j}) \rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^{J} \lambda_{j}T(w_{j}) = T(w)$$

Comment: It's important to note here that $J$ is a *finite* number (which depends on $w$).

Comment: @NateEldredge okay good point, I have corrected it